# SELECT DISTINCT HAVING Count unique conditions

Tags: sql

I've searched for an answer on this but can't find quite how to get this distinct recordset based on a condition.  I have a table with the following sample data:

```
Type    Color   Location    Supplier
----    -----   --------    --------
Apple   Green   New York    ABC
Apple   Green   New York    XYZ
Apple   Green   Los Angeles ABC
Apple   Red     Chicago     ABC
Apple   Red     Chicago     XYZ
Apple   Red     Chicago     DEF
Banana  Yellow  Miami       ABC
Banana  Yellow  Miami       DEF
Banana  Yellow  Miami       XYZ
Banana  Yellow  Atlanta     ABC
```

I'd like to create a query that shows the count of unique locations for each distinct Type+Color where the number of unique locations is more than 1, e.g.

```
Type    Color   UniqueLocations
----    -----   --------
Apple   Green   2
Banana  Yellow  2
```

Note that {Apple, Red, 1} doesn't appear because there is only 1 location for red apples (Chicago).  I think I've got this one (but perhaps there is a simpler method).  I'm using:

```
SELECT Type, Color, Count(Location) FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Type, Color, Location FROM MyTable)
GROUP BY Type, Color HAVING Count(Location)>1;
```

How can I create another query that lists the `Type, Color`, and `Location` for each distinct `Type,Color` when the count of unique locations for that `Type,Color` is greater than 1?  The resulting recordset would look like:

```
Type    Color   Location
----    -----   --------
Apple   Green   New York
Apple   Green   Los Angeles
Banana  Yellow  Miami
Banana  Yellow  Atlanta
```

Note that `Apple, Red, Chicago` doesn't appear because there is only 1 location for red apples.  Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a `COUNT(DISTINCT Location)` and join against a subquery on `Type` and `Color`  The `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses as you have attempted to use them will do the job.

```
/* Be sure to use DISTINCT in the outer query to de-dup */
SELECT DISTINCT
   MyTable.Type,
   MyTable.Color,
   Location
FROM 
  MyTable
  INNER JOIN (
    /* Joined subquery returns type,color pairs having COUNT(DISTINCT Location) > 1 */
    SELECT
      Type,
      Color,
      /* Don't actually need to select this value - it could just be in the HAVING */
      COUNT(DISTINCT Location) AS UniqueLocations
    FROM
      MyTable
    GROUP BY Type, Color
    /* Note: Some RDBMS won't allow the alias here and you 
       would have to use the expanded form
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Location) > 1
     */
    HAVING UniqueLocations > 1
  /* JOIN back against the main table on Type, Color */
  ) subq ON MyTable.Type = subq.Type AND MyTable.Color = subq.Color
```

[Here is a demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0618f/4)

Answer (score 8):

You could write your first query as this:

```
Select Type, Color, Count(Distinct Location) As UniqueLocations
From Table
Group By Type, Color
Having Count(Distinct Location) > 1
```

*(if you're using MySQL you could use the alias `UniqueLocations` in your `having` clause, but on many other systems the aliases are not yet available as the `having` clause is evaluated before the `select` clause, in this case you have to repeat the count on both clauses).*

And for the second one, there are many different ways to write that, this could be one:

```
Select Distinct Type, Color, Location
From Table
Where
  Exists (
    Select
      *
    From
      Table Table_1
    Where
      Table_1.Type = Table.Type
      and Table_1.Color = Table.Color
    Group By
      Type, Color
    Having
      Count(Distinct Location) > 1
  )
```

Comment: first bit does not work. It does not recognise "UniqueLocations"

Comment: @EliPerpinyal what DBMS are you using?

Comment: @fthiella MS Sql

Comment: @EliPerpinyal thank you, the OP is probably using MySQL but I've updated my answer and now the code should work on most systems